# Erro ao usar react-native-camera

Tags: front-end, react-native

Olá,

Estou precisando colocar o aplicativo para ler o QRCode e no tutorial que estou achando fala para usar o react-native-camera. Só que não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar a câmera do celular.

Já fiz a configuração que fala no tópico do link
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/installation.md#requirements

Mesmo assim continua dando erro e não abre o aplicativo. Segue o erro:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-camera:compileGeneralDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to
get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (D:\Projetos_ReactNative\Exemplos\reactnativecamera\node_modules\@r
eact-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:75
:39)
    at buildAndRun (D:\Projetos_ReactNative\Exemplos\reactnativecamera\node_modules\@react
-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:137:41)
    at then.result (D:\Projetos_ReactNative\Exemplos\reactnativecamera\node_modules\@react
-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:103:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: Qual a versão do react-native você está utilizando?

Comment: "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.0",

Comment: @AlexPassos android ou IOS?

Answer (score -1):

A versão 0.60 é muito recente (03/07/2019) portanto são muitas as bibliotecas disponíveis que ainda não estão atualizadas as documentações. A [nova versão](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases) trás a função de auto link das bibliotecas e e suporte ao AndroidX. Com isso alguns passos necessários nas documentações não são mais úteis.

**Solução com downgrade**

- Abra o arquivo `package.json` que está na pasta raiz do projeto.
- Procure por `react-native": "0.60.0"`
- Altere para `react-native": "0.59.10"` e salve o arquivo.
- Abra o terminal e corra o comando `npm install`
- Verifique se deu erto com o comando `react-native --version`

Obs: Para manter a sua plicação com a versão mais atualizada pode-se utiliza o 
[jetifier](https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier)

**Solução com Jetifier**

- Instale a biblioteca com o comando `npm install --save-dev jetifier` ou `yarn add -D jetifier`
- Feito isso, é possível rodar o comando `npx jetify` que irá atualizar todas as dependencias para utilizar o AndroidX.
- A cada instalação é necessário rodar o comando acima (para facilitar e não precisar rodar o comando a cada nova instalação), precisamos fazer mais uma configuração no arquivo package.json, adicionando:

  ```
  "scripts": {
      "postinstall": "npx jetify"
      ...
  }
  ```

Com a utilização de um dos métodos o projeto deve compilar sem problemas, levando em consideração que todas as configurações das bibliotecas estejam devidamente corretas.

Comment: Vou tentar para ver se resolve. Valeu

Comment: Atualizar a versão pra anterior? não indicaria o @AlexPassos fazer isso, até porque dá versão 0.59 para 0.60 tivemos links automáticos(o que facilitou demais). Sem falar em outros problemas, a ideia é atualizar e não retroceder a versão